# How to add multistep registration form in default user registration

Tags: 7, forms, users

I need to create a user registration form in Drupal 7. My requirement is as follows:-

1. I want to use the default Drupal 7 User Registration Form i.e admin/config/people/accounts
2. Form must appear in popup/modal when user click on "Create new account" in User Login Form
3. Form should be Multistep i.e there will be 3/4 steps of filling the form.
4. Customize the form in such a way that UserName, Password and Email
   appears on last step of the form.

Please let me know if it is possible in Drupal 7 default user registration form and how?

Answer (score 1):

You can try [Field group](http://drupal.org/project/field_group)

> Fieldgroup will, as the name implies, group fields together. All
>   fieldable entities will have the possibility to add groups to wrap
>   their fields together. Fieldgroup comes with default HTML wrappers
>   like vertical tabs, horizontal tabs, accordions, fieldsets or div
>   wrappers.

**Available group types**

- Fieldsets
- Horizontal tabs
- Vertical tabs
- Accordions
- Divs
- Multipage steps: **Note: This is only client side.**

The idea is to use *Multipage steps* to make the form steps.

Comment: I tried "Multipage Steps" of Field group in user registration page but no luck. All I am able to see all the group contents in one page rather than showing in different pages. It works good when implemented in creation of content types but did not succeed when work in default Drupal 7 User Registration Form

Comment: Here i found something http://drupal.org/node/999420

Answer (score 1):

Go through the [Tutorial: Ten Step-by-Step Code Samples for Learning Form API](http://drupal.org/node/262422), and check with Forms API.

or the following link : [Building a Multistep Registration Form in Drupal 7](http://grasmash.com/article/building-multistep-registration-form-drupal-7).

Comment: I am looking for some available modules which can be implemented as Multisteps in default user registration in Drupal 7. Please let me know if any existing module is available as solution.

Comment: I fallowed same as in  link Building a Multistep Registration Form in Drupal 7. but when  i fill values in step1 and go to step2 and again come to step1, the values filled previously in step1 not showing.Please suggest me how to sort out this issue